# Android:save captured image format from JPEG to PNG in internal storage directory

Tags: java, xml

In Eclipse,i have Captured Image from emulator and it save the format as JPEG.But i want to save the image format as PNG. How can i convert image format from JPEG to PNG.

Here I am using this code to save the image in directory.

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss");
    String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
   String photoFile = "Picture_" + date + ".PNG";
// String photoFile = "Picture_" + date + ".JPEG";
    String filename = pictureFileDir.getPath() + File.separator + photoFile;

    File pictureFile = new File(filename);

    try {
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);

      fos.write(data);

      fos.close();
      Toast.makeText(context, "New Image saved:" + photoFile,
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception error) {
      //Log.d(IntersaActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "File" + filename + "not saved: "+ error.getMessage());
      Toast.makeText(context, "Image could not be saved.",
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here the code for creating image file using Bitmap class

**Edit**

you need to first open your existing image file into this bmp object and in file object give another name for save.

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName);// here you need to pass your existing file path


File image = new File(your_sdcard_file_path);
FileOutputStream outStream;
try {
    image.createFile(); // need to create file as empty first if it was exist already then change the name
    outStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
// here you need to pass the format as I have passed as PNG so you can create the file with specific format
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream); 
    /* 100 to keep full quality of the image */

    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();
    success = true;
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: :Thanks for your reply.Here i am facing some problem .when i using this code into eclipse and captured the image.then the image is stored in the DDMS.then the captured image size was 0bytes and when i opened the image it shows JPEG Format only.How to change PNG Format? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: :Thanks for your Response.Here i am storing the image file in the InternalStorageDirectory.I declare the filepath name as Myfile and directory name is Camera.how can i declare the pathname in decod file?Iam using this code to store the images in the local file directory.private File getDir(){ String filepath = "MyFileStorage";
ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(context);
File sdDir = contextWrapper.getDir(filepath, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);//File sdDir=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);return new File(sdDir, "CameraAPIDemo");}

Comment: pathname will be your jpeg file name with full path which was also stored into the sdcard

Comment: :Thanks for your response.I want to store the capture image in internal storage directory not in External Storage Directory(SD Card).thanks in advance.